# Re factoring if's to a hash

Tags: perl, if-statement, hash

How do you refactor these bunch of ifs into a hash ?
I don't want to have a whole lot of if statements in my code. Can I use hashing instead? If yes, how?

```
if($ENV{'test.version'} eq "version8"){
 INCLUDE("$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}/bbl/version8/common_64_knobs.bbl");
}

if($ENV{'test.version'} eq "version7" && $ENV{'test.mode'} eq "a"){
 INCLUDE("$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}/bbl/common_32_knobs_a.bbl");
}

if($ENV{'test.version'} eq "version7" && $ENV{'test.mode'} eq "b"){
 INCLUDE("$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}/bbl/common_32_knobs_b.bbl");
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Id on't want to have a whole lot of if statements in my code. Rather can I use hashing here ? if yes, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something similar to the following:

```
my %includes = (
    version8 => {
        '*' => "$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}/bbl/version8/common_64_knobs.bbl",
    },
    version7 => {
        a => "$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}/bbl/common_32_knobs_a.bbl",
        b => "$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}/bbl/common_32_knobs_b.bbl",
    },
);

if ( my $inc = $includes{ $ENV{'test.version'} }{ $ENV{'test.mode'} }
            || $includes{ $ENV{'test.version'} }{ '*' } )
{
    INCLUDE($inc);
}
```

And obviously, if `$ENV{'TEST_ROOT'}` is in all of your values, you could extrapolate that out of the hash of hash values and just put it in the `INCLUDE` call.